# renaming file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have tons of image inside a folder and it also has different file types. I have tried googling for an answer but I can't seem to find one. I wanted the files to be named 1.jpg, 2.png, 3.gif. . . n.JPEG. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: You can use rename or a loop

Comment: have a look at `man rename` (which is a perl tool, maybe you have to install perl).

Comment: what does the `perlexp` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below:

```
cd path_to_your_files
declare -i i=0; for f in *; do i=$((i+1));fn=$i".${f##*.}"; mv "$f" "$fn"; done
```

Make note that the command above is a bash script.

Comment: Should the path be a string? It gives me an error `mv: cannot stat ‘/home/vianney/Downloads/Image Processing/Images/*’: No such file or directory`

Comment: I edited my command. And are you sure that your OS is using BASH as in the default?

Comment: Check default shell by: `echo $SHELL`

Comment: result of `echo $SHELL` == `/bin/bash`

Comment: show me the output of command: `for f in  path_to_your_files/*; do echo "$f", done;`

Comment: Sir. I would like to ask if how if I would like to transfer it to another folder? How could I possibly tweak your code. Thank you

Comment: I solved it already sir @Nguyen Sy Thanh Son :D Thank you very much.